# Implementing chat commands

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, parsing

I'm new to C++ and I'm writting some kind of chat server and client who talk to each other through commands for learning purposes. I serialize and deserialize these commands using a JSON library. My first approach has been to create a base class called Command and have a derived class for each command.

The use case would be to be able to directly create objects of the derived classes on the client and to call a deserialize function that will return an object of the derived class on the server. I have something like this.

```
enum class Commands {
    NAME = 0,
    QUIT,
    WHISPER,
    JOIN,
    CREATE,
    UNKNOWN
};

class Command {
    protected:
        Commands command;
    public:
        Commands getCommandType();
        virtual Message serialize();
        static Command* deserialize(Message message);
};
```

I thought it would be better to leave command private and make the Command constructor initialize that value and then for every derived class, have it call the "super" constructor. But I don't know if this is a good approach in C++.
I serialize the enum too because each command will have a different number of fields when serialized. For the implementation of deserialize I have this:

```
Command* Command::deserialize(Message message) {
    auto parsed_message = json::parse(message);
    if (parsed_message["type"] != "command") {
        throw "Unexpected message";
    }

    //Insert every command.
    if (parsed_message["command"] == Commands::QUIT) {
        return QuitCommand::deserialize(message);
    }
    if (parsed_message["command"] == Commands::NAME) {
        return NameCommand::deserialize(message);
    }
    if (parsed_message["command"] == Commands::WHISPER) {
        return WhisperCommand::deserialize(message);
    }

    throw "Unknown command";
}
```

And then as an example for a deserialize method:

```
NameCommand* NameCommand::deserialize(Message message) {
    auto parsed_message = json::parse(message);

    if (parsed_message["type"] == "command" && parsed_message["command"] == Commands::NAME) {
        return new NameCommand(parsed_message["name"]);
    } else {
        throw "NAME command not valid";
    }
}
```

Now, the code right now works (or at least it seems like it does), but I don't see how it is maintainable or well structued. Could anyone please give me their opinion of the code?

Comment: It's hard to review because a lot is missing. It's not clear, for example, why `NameCommand` and `QuitCommand` are different classes or what they do.

Comment: I think you should add the implementation of each command. Don't worry about your post being long.